# Transforming GPS tracks to line segments, and retaining start_time and end_time?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

I have a long GPS track representing a route of boat survey, which looks like:

> Id    X   Y   time
>   1 274604  2778803     2016/5/5 08:31:34
>   2 274589  2778804     2016/5/5 08:31:49
>   3 274564  2778811     2016/5/5 08:32:04
>   4 274538  2778818     2016/5/5 08:32:19
>   5 274511  2778822     2016/5/5 08:32:34
>    ...

For analysis, I transformed this point layer into polyline, and then split the line into 100 equal segments.

How can I get the information of start time and end time of each segment?

Something like:

> SegmentId time_start time_end
>   1 2016/5/5 08:31:34   2016/5/5 08:50:00
>   2 2016/5/5 08:50:00   2016/5/5 09:12:25
>   3 2016/5/5 09:12:25   2016/5/5 09:35:12
>   ...

I approached it by Spatial Join, but it's erroneous, because the route has some overlapped parts (same coordinates but different time).

Comment: You had a tag for ArcGIS 10.2 and mention Spatial Join so I'm changing that tag to ArcGIS Desktop. You do not mention R in your question so I am removing that tag.

Comment: Would you accept an R solution? Also - does each segment begin with the last node of the previous segment?

Comment: Thank you, @Simbamangu. A R solution is also welcome. Yes, each segment begins with the last node of the previous segment.